# kube-apiserver high RAM usage

Tags: kubernetes, kube-apiserver

Upgraded recently from v1.9.1 to v1.9.6 of kubernetes. Everything is running fine but the kube-apiserver memory usage has hugely increased and is sitting just over 900mb as standard.

It's not a huge issue as there is available RAM for it to do so but wondered if there was a way to diagnose what might cause this RAM increase. The boxes havent changed i.e. there is the same amount of free RAM as there always was available, but kube-apiserver is being a lot more greedy with it

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [changelogs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.9.md#changelog-since-v196), they expand the functionality of custom api-server:

- The webhook admission controller in a custom apiserver now works off-the-shelf. ([#60995](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/60995), [@caesarxuchao](https://github.com/caesarxuchao))

Therefore, that may cause increasing of ram usage.